# How to reboot system if specific directory modified as a systemd service

Tags: command-line, 18.04

I'm trying to create systemd service to reboot device. When `hello.txt` file content or file modified, system needs to reboot. I try to achieve but I don't know rebooting indefinitely. Here is my systemd service description;

`sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/path_watcher.service` gives:

```
[Unit]
Description=path restarter
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/reboot
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And

```
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/path_watcher.path
```

gives:

```
[Path]
PathModified=/home/nvidia/Videos/hello.txt

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Can anyone help me out for this use case.

Comment: Be sure that your reboot script properly logs the reason why it's rebooting, else your service will be indistinguishable from a hardware failure and correspondingly difficult to debug.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks for the reply. I didn't write any logs. the systemd service will works or needs to modify. pls give me any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

set `ExecStart=your bash script` ,and do what you want in the script.